# List of Sketchpad Apps for Windows 7 Tablet edition

Tags: windows-7, user-experience

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad x200 tablet and got it with hopes that I could use it during presentations to quickly annotate my screen and also switch to skecthpad mode to draw images instead of using the traditional whiteboard/marker or easel w/paper method. Doing this would allow my notes to be captured by the video camera taping the presentation.

I was disappointed to find out that windows does not have anything like this that ships with Windows 7 Tablet edition.

The coolest thing I found so far was Autodesk Sketchpad Pro. I remember that Compiz Fusion has a feature to hit a keyboard shortcut and write fire, magic lights etc on the screen and am looking for something like this.

I need a list of programs for Windows 7 that are sketchpad/annotation programs for Windows 7 Tablets.

Thanks

Comment: This would make a good community wiki question.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Office OneNote 2007, I found, was essential when I got my tablet.  I got it for my final year in college and took 100% of my course notes using it.  It has various pen modes, highlighting, and built-in handwriting recognition (for instance, if you want to text search your scribbles).  I had one course where the professor would teach and use OneNote on his tablet, projected on the screen, instead of a whiteboard.

It won't let you write over your screen like Compiz, but I think it's more practical (unless you actually do want to markup the Windows desktop, that is).

I know that Powerpoint also allows you to annotate/sketch over the slides while you are presenting.

Comment: Great info, I will look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 tablet PCs come with Windows Journal... I find it pretty simple to use. I wish it had a few more features, but it's pretty great. And it can convert your writing into text.